# Comparing stock levels with WINDOW functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data that looks like this:

| sku | stock_level | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| widget | 15 | 4/7 |
| widget | 12 | 4/8 |
| widget | 10 | 4/9 |
| widget | 9 | 4/10 |
| widget | 25 | 4/11 |
| widget | 22 | 4/12 |

I’m trying to solve a problem that’s similar to the ‘Comparing close prices with WINDOW functions’ problem given here: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/sql-for-stock-market-analysis-f2145031e125

Basically, I want to know the change in stock level of a widget from the previous day. I figured out that part by following the example in the link, using the LAG function.

I have a requirement that I’m trying to implement:
When the change is positive (e.g. change is +16 on 4/11), I want to instead return the average change of the last 3 days, rather than +16.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
   sku,
   created_at,
   ROUND(stock_level, 2) AS actual_level,
   ROUND(LAG(stock_level, 1) OVER (
      ORDER BY created_at), 2) AS one_day_before_level
FROM pings
WHERE sku = 'widget'
)
SELECT
   sku,
   (actual_level - one_day_before_level) AS change,
   created_at
FROM temp_table;
```

Returns:

| sku | change | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| widget | null | 4/7 |
| widget | -3 | 4/8 |
| widget | -2 | 4/9 |
| widget | -1 | 4/10 |
| widget | 16 | 4/11 |
| widget | -3 | 4/12 |

I want to ultimately return this:

| sku | change | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| widget | null | 4/7 |
| widget | -3 | 4/8 |
| widget | -2 | 4/9 |
| widget | -1 | 4/10 |
| widget | -2 (This is average change of widget over the last 3 days) | 4/11 |
| widget | -3 | 4/12 |

What is a good method to calculate the average change of the last 3 days, whenever I encounter a positive change? Is this possible? I'm using Postgres if that matters.

Comment: What if it is positive several days in a row?  I don't thing your description is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this:

```
select p.*,
       (case when lag(stock_level) < stock_level
             then (lag(stock_level, 1) - lag(stock_level, 4) ) / 3
             else stock_level - lag(stock_level)
        end) as diff
from pings p
where sku = 'widget';
```

The arithmetic expression in the `then` clause is just another way of calculating the average you want.

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that expression for the average.

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . You're right.  The `1` and `4` were in the wrong order.

Comment: I should have noticed it was just a change in sign and the intermediate terms cancel. Duh.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out, super useful!